# How Can You Tell If IPSec Is Installed on Cisco

Tags: cisco, configuration, router, ipsec, verification

How can I tell if my Cisco router has IPSec installed? I went into configuration mode to see about setting up a crypto policy, but the `'crypto'` keyword isn't available. Is this an indication that it isn't installed or am I doing something wrong?

**Edit**: After running the `show version | include IOS` command, I see 2 of my routers are:

`C2600-IPBASE-M Version 12.3(7) T3`

and my other 2 routers are:

`C2800NM-IPBASE-M Version 12.4(3g)`

Comment: what version of IOS are you running? Is it a 'k9' image?

Comment: I do not see 'k9' when I run the 'show version | include IOS' command. See my modified question above with the output from that command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need the Advanced IP Services image on the 2600 platform to get full crypto, the IP Base only does ipsec through nat according to the [Cisco Feature Navigator](http://tools.cisco.com/ITDIT/CFN/jsp/index.jsp)

Comment: I think you're right. I'm trying to set up an IPSec Tunnel, but it doesn't seem I can as is. Maybe if I find the original installation media, it will have the option to install what I'm missing.

Comment: If you have an active support contract you should be able to pull down the right image from support.cisco.com

Comment: Unfortunately, we don't as these are old routers that were purchased for lab R&D efforts.

Comment: Do I need a particular hardware module in addition to the software or could I use the router as is so long as I have the right image installed?

Answer (score 1):

Please run `show version | include IOS` and see if the output shows `K9` in the image.

Sample output: `Cisco IOS Software, C2900 Software (C2900-UNIVERSALK9-M), Version 15.2(4)M6, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc2)`

Comment: I've modified my question to display the output of that command. It did not say K9 anywhere.